# url decoder Python3

Tags: python-3.x, url, decoder

I have this code

```
@login_required
@render_to(appName+':search.html')
@append_permission_context()
def view(request):
id = request.GET.get("v", "")
  context = { 
     "number" : id
 }
  context_vars = vars_base(request)
    context.update(context_vars)
    return base(request, context)
```

which links me in my front to this url: https://......../search/?v=MzA=

Looks it is not enable to decode "?v=MzA=". Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

equals sign should be encoded (this is same for space, quotes and so on)

your url request should looks like: `https://.../search/?v=MzA%3D`